# Website crashed after enabling SSL

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, prestashop

Yesterday I enabled SSL and dedicated IP as I upgraded my Bluehost account, but after enabling it the website stopped working. I spoke to Bluehost, they told me to insert a code in .htaccess which I did with no success.

After that, I spoke to them again and they said the.htaccess is misconfigured. Now the thing is that I have no idea how to fix the htacess file.

I can see that there is too much code in it, but I don't know how to fix it. Right now, it's a mess. I tried regenerating the file but the code remained just the same.

Is anyone here able to help me, please?

My website is heightd.com. The error I am getting is 500 error and before that I was getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Here is how the .htaccess file looks like:

```
# ~~start~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
# .htaccess automaticaly generated by PrestaShop e-commerce open-source solution
# http://www.prestashop.com - http://www.prestashop.com/forums

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on


#Domain: heightd.com
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api$ api/ [L]

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Images
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([0-9]+)(\-[\.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/c/$1$2.jpg [L]
# AlphaImageLoader for IE and fancybox
RewriteRule ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 [L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|svg)$">
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404

# ~~end~~ Do not remove this comment, Prestashop will keep automatically the code outside this comment when .htaccess will be generated again
```

Comment: First of all you should disable and then enable again Friendly URLs - it is used to regenerate .htaccess file. Isn't is possible to restore an old .htaccess file from a backup?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I enabled and disabled the Friendly URLs when the problem first appeared, but the .htaccess file looks the same every time. I restored my entire website to from a backup and it's working, but I can's enable SSL on it. As I can see, although I am not an advanced developer, the .htaccess file has way too much code in it, but I cannot seem to find an old one that has less code.

Comment: Could you show the code that Bluehost told you to insert? If you have a fresh .htaccess from a backup, the problem may be related to their configuration. What's the way to activate the cert? Is is shared hosting or VPS? This tool may be useful to check your cert: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: You may try to force SSL on every page and check what happens. It's good to disable cache in your browser or use incognito mode and disable template recompilation & cache via back office. I've checked your cert and it's "F" - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=heightd.com You should send those information to the Bluehost.